# BB 10 App Crashing in device,but working good in simulator

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have developed an BB 10 app, It is working well in the simulator.The same app is not working in the device.I  want to know , why it is crashing in device.

Is there any way to know the reason for crashing after installing in the device, so that i can fix it.

I have created a log file in the **Device Documents**

Is there any signal / listener OR try and catch mechanism, to write that exception into the log file?

my bar-descriptor.xml is like this, Please find.

```
 <!-- Request permission to execute native code.  Required for native applications. -->
<permission system="true">run_native</permission>
<permission>read_device_identifying_information</permission>
<permission>access_pimdomain_messages</permission>
<permission>access_internet</permission>
<permission system="true">_sys_use_consumer_push</permission>
<permission>access_sms_mms</permission>
<permission>post_notification</permission>
<permission>access_shared</permission>
<permission>bbm_connect</permission>
<env var="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="app/native/lib:/usr/lib/qt4/lib"/>
```

Please help,

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given much to go on but here are some things to check right off the bat:

1. If the application isn't signed, and you don't have a debug token, or the token has expired or development mode has expired on the device the application will exit from the splash screen.
2. If you aren't requesting all necessary permissions in you app-descriptor.xml file your application may be getting unexpected results that cause the crash.
3. If you have a higher OS version on the simulator than the device, you may be using QML that isn't recognized by the device QML compiler which will cause a crash when the returned QML document is null. This is usually logged to the console.

If it isn't one of those, use the IDE run the application on the device and see if there is anything useful logged to the console. If not, set the IDE into debug mode to run the program under the debugger on the device. It will halt execution where the application is aborting. This may be deep in a system library but you may be able to step up the call stack to your code to find out the location of the problem.

Comment: Previously before allowing my App to connect with BBM it worked on the device.nut now it is not working. For more Information I am editing the question with bar-discriminator file. please find

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your bar-descriptor.xml but I see you have accepted my answer. Did you find the source of the crash?

Comment: It is working now..The mistake I did was...After changing the signing keys to some other sign keys...In my bar-descriptor.xml file <Author> Tag was missed. After adding it to my latest bar-descriptor.xml file,It worked for me, Thanks!!!